# Usage of Ternary expressions in javascript with two operands

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

```
a ? b.deleteList() : "";
```

This is a bug according to sonar. How to correct this ??

Comment: What error does Sonar report?

Answer (score 2):

Sonar's documentation should be telling you what to do about it.

That code is an `if` statement in disguise (an even worse version of the one abusing the `&&` operator: `a && b.deleteList();`). The solution is to make it an `if` statement:

```
if (a) {
    b.deleteList();
}
```

Looking at [Sonar's rules](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-1774?search=ternary), it doesn't seem to like the conditional operator (which it calls¹ the "ternary operator") at all, not even when it's the right-hand side of an expression. While I don't agree with that (in my view, using a conditional operator when you're using the operator's result is okay in some, even many, situations), there's no question that abusing it in the way shown in the code you've quoted is poor practice.

---

¹ The name of the `x ? y : z` operator is the *conditional operator*. It's **a** ternary operator (an operator that accepts three operands), and it's currently JavaScript's only ternary operator, but there could be others in the future.